# Is there any automation tool which makes easy for me to test Android UI?

Tags: android

I wanted to avoid the UI Issues on Different versions on android. This making me mess, since i dont have much devices on my hand. but still i have emulator but i have to do repeated for all the OS version.

I have tried MonkeyRunner which is taking long time for me to write scripts. I have tried Robotium but since i am a tester for me i am not much aware of that tool but i have followed the steps on the site but i end up with failure most of the time. IS there any automation tool to avoid this UI Issues and making little simpler for me.

Answer (score 3):

Two that I know of:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android

http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk

Comment: Hi, Monkey Talk i need source code as well. I have only .apk files... will it work out for calabash-android? If yes, please give me the link to set up the things..

Answer (score 2):

I recently reviewed a number of UI testing frameworks:

Perfecto Mobile is a cloud-based testing system that supports Android, iPhone, WinMo, BB.  They use OCR to verify the expected results are displayed on the screen.

UI/Application Exerciser Monkey is a Python-based system for Android (not iPhone) device or emulator, allows you to save results as screenshots and programatically compare against known-good screenshots.

Robolectric is good if you want to run fast-running unit tests (probably not for you)

I've gone with [calabash-android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) which is based on Robotium, but uses Cucumber to wrap it in Behaviour Driven Development syntax.

- You write your test cases in plain english (there are a number of steps provided to get you started, but you can customise it as much as you want)
- Your test cases can run on Android or iPhone
- You can run on an emulator, your device or [lesspainful.com](http://www.lesspainful.com)

Answer (score 2):

For Android it´s definitely [TestObject](http://www.testobject.com).

"TestObjects provides mobile app UI-testing as a Software-as-a-Service. Our users can just sign up within minutes and get access to real and virtual mobile devices and automation tools from their browser."

Answer (score 1):

Google's new testing tool: uiautomator - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There is Testdroid Recorder http://testdroid.com/product/testdroid-recorder

it wrapps Robotium.

Not free though. Cost 200$ for 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

The guide at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html may be of use. It talks about using a patched version of ChimpChat (the Java MonkeyRunner implementation) to interact with the Android UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following test automation tools: ranorex and seeTest.

http://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/android-test-automation.html

http://experitest.com/

Just go and see whether it satisfies your requirements

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest (http://experitest.com/) can be handy when needing to test different devices (different OS version or resolutions).
Instead of using images to identify elements you can use Native/Web properties. Therefore, instead of relying on the device, you can rely on the app so that there is no need to create a new test for every device but only one tests to run on all devices.